# bootnode: command not found

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am attempting to start a PoA network on my local machine using a Geth Clique PoA network. When I go to initialize bootnode via a bash script, I receive the following error:

```
./bootnode/bootnode-start-local.sh: line 1: bootnode: command not found
```

I thought bootnode was installed when you install geth? Is there a way to add it to the $PATH? I don't have any issues running geth commands.

I am currently running MacOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you installed up-to-date geth via Homebrew on macOS.
The command `bootnode` should be available from `/usr/local/bin/`, refer to [geth docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth).

Either use `/usr/local/bin/bootnode` within your `bootnode-start-local.sh` script or add it to your path by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/bootnode:$PATH` to `~/.profile`.

In general, `/usr/local/bin/` is probably not in your path, you can add it via `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH` to `~/.profile`.

Comment: I reinstalled geth 1.9.20 via homebrew. `bootnode` is not listed in `/usr/local/bin`. I also made sure to update XCode as well because I've run into issues on Mac previously when it wasn't up to date.

Comment: Did you try to download and install geth 1.19.20 including tools from [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/index.html)?